# Docker: How to fix "Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use docker in Manjaro (my kernel version is 4.19) and it is not working.

After running `sudo pamac install docker` I run `sudo systemctl start docker.service` and receive this message:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So `sudo systemctl status docker.service` returns:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-04-29 12:28:44 -03; 39s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 17769 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17769 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

and `journalctl -xe` returns:

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A unidade docker.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A unidade docker.service falhou.
-- 
-- O resultado é failed.
abr 29 12:28:44 tamer-pc systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The unit docker.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
abr 29 12:29:02 tamer-pc dbus-daemon[650]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.resolve1' unit='>
abr 29 12:29:02 tamer-pc dbus-daemon[650]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.>
abr 29 12:29:24 tamer-pc sudo[17879]:    tamer : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/docker ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl stat>
abr 29 12:29:24 tamer-pc sudo[17879]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
abr 29 12:29:24 tamer-pc sudo[17879]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 1703-1725/1725 (END)
```

I'm looking for resolution for two days but whatever I read seems not to be exactly the same as my problem.

Comment: Try to start the docker daemon manually in debug mode and watch for any error messages: `sudo dockerd --debug`

Comment: I run this command, [this](https://pastebin.com/9Dde458f) u can see the pastebin of output. Basically its got stop in the line `API listen on /var/run/docker.sock`, after 25 minutes i lost my patience and run `ctrl+c`. After I run `sudo systemctl status docker.service` and the output is different.

Comment: Lol actually now I run `sudo systemctl start docker.serive` and i got [this](https://pastebin.com/3XR7WRvu)

Comment: try restarting network with  `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service` then reboot

Comment: This one might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927097/13875968

Comment: I faced the same error, neither systemctl restart docker, nor linux reboot worked for me.  the only clue to solve error was `docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly` . I ran the command `sudo dockerd --debug` it exactly showed the error point in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` config file. so I fixed the configuration and then start docker service solved the problem.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I really dont know what was happening, but I run `sudo dockerd --debug` like Zeitounator orients me, reboot my pc and docker works perfectly.

Comment: That's truly weird but rebooting works wonders. I installed docker on my Ubuntu 18.04 following the official manual.

Comment: The command made me aware that my Linux kernel is too old for running Docker.

`[root@ubersmith-web docker]# dockerd --debug
INFO[2020-08-12T03:53:32.984460717-04:00] Starting up
DEBU[2020-08-12T03:53:32.984943597-04:00] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
FATA[2020-08-12T03:53:32.985099147-04:00] Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32.042stab140.1ovz is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.`

Comment: For me the error was:
```failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-144-generic
``` and the fix was ```apt-get install -y linux-modules-4.15.0-144-generic```

Comment: Running `dockerd --debug` revealed a formatting issue with `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Comment: Yes, same worked for me. reboot worked!!

Comment: Run `sudo dockerd --debug` without reboot worked for me

Comment: After ``# dockerd --debug`` I get information:
``unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: merged configuration validation from file and command line flags failed: the "graph" config file option is deprecated; use "data-root" instead``
I guess it's happen on docker 23.0.0 (debian package: docker-ce:5:23.0.0-0~debian.11~bullseye ). It fix after update ``daemon.json`` and restart daemon.

Comment: how did you guys even reach to that point? I got stuck on this "INFO[2023-03-23T19:38:15.021555465+08:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock "

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar issue when setting up **Kubernetes** on my local machine:

The error came up when I tried setting up **Docker** to use the OverlayFS storage driver.

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
cp -au /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bk
```

And then when I tried to start docker again using the command below:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

It was throwing the error:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

I ran the command below to inspect the issue following [Tâmer Pinheiro answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55911400/10907864):

```
sudo dockerd --debug
```

And it gave me this information:

```
INFO[2020-09-02T11:46:15.272833297Z] Starting up                                  
DEBU[2020-09-02T11:46:15.273547501Z] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
failed to start daemon: Unable to get the TempDir under /var/lib/docker: mkdir
/var/lib/docker/tmp: no space left on device
```

I also checked the disk space of the server:

```
df -h
```

which showed that there was no space left on the drive (`/dev/sda1 filesystem`):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   12M  384M   4% /run
/dev/sda1       9.8G  9.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

And I realized that the issue had to do with no space left on device.

I had to run the following commands to clear some space for the filesystem:

```
sudo find /var/log -type f -delete
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
sudo apt clean all
```

And then finally, I removed the `/var/lib/docker.bk` file, because it was too large for the **9.8GB filesystem** of the server:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker.bk
```

This time when I ran the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

everything worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, but I folow the advise of @Zeitounator, and I run this command `sudo dockerd --debug` to see the problem. It display this message :

> Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab138.1 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.

I've update my kernel and it works perfectly. I hope that help you !

Answer (score 8):

For me,Stopping the VPN solved the problem

Comment: wow, wouldnt have thought of this right away. Not sure why tho, only starting out with Docker atm.

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was a dangling comma in /etc/docker/daemon.json in the "dns" array/list. I simply removed the comma after the last entry and it worked.

Comment: Similarly, I had an empty `daemon.json` file which also prevented Docker from starting.

Answer (score 8):

Facing the same issue Three steps:

1:`docker --debug`
to identify the issue it comes out to be network issue:  Failed to program NAT chain: ZONE_CONFLICT: 'docker0' already bound to a zone

2: To resolved this Googled and found the command to run

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0
```

3: `systemctl start docker`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I tried so many other methods for over an hour, from uninstalling all packages to rebooting, and this is the only solution that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had a missing comma in my `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Comment: Same here, I had a wrong subnet digit: `192.168.0.0/166` is not valid because it should be `192.168.0.0/16` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after Running dockerd --debug, it shows `failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay2: unknown option overlay2.override_kernel_check: overlay2`.

**Cause**:
Docker supports several different graph drivers using a pluggable architecture. The preferred driver is overlay2 followed by overlay. However, Support for the overlay2.override_kernel_check storage option is removed from Docker v24.

**Resolution**:
This storage option must be removed from the Docker daemon configuration in /etc/docker/daemon.json file.

The current file content:

```
{
        "storage-driver": "overlay2",
        "storage-opts": [
                "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
        ],
        "log-driver": "journald",
        "selinux-enabled": true
}
```

After removing the storage option:

```
{
        "storage-driver": "overlay2",
        "log-driver": "journald",
        "selinux-enabled": true
}
```

then execute `systemctl restart docker` and `systemctl status docker.service`, it shows `active (running)`

Answer (score 2):

I followed various steps that lead me to this error. Then just restarted my PC and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I assume it was because I had done a docker compose down and rebooted my machine before it was actually finished, so something got corrupted.

Since I couldn't use the daemon, I managed to follow the following steps to clean corrupted files without using the daemon. I got those snippets on a thread teaching how to completely uninstall docker from ubuntu.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an error "Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code." after installing the Docker on Centos 8. What helped me is:

```
yum install iptables
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I run "sudo systemctl start docker" with a success.

Answer (score 1):

For me , I tried

```
sudo dockerd --debug
```

the last line error is

```
Error starting daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
```

and I deleted the metadata, and it worked:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db.bk
```

Answer (score 1):

After read the release notes, I undestand that my config must be update:

Remove the `-g` and `--graph` daemon options in favor of `--data-root`.
https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/3739

[Follow this docker community link](https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-docker-service-fail-to-start-after-update/134444)

If this does not work try reboot and try again, We are doing all tha Jetson Nano Devices

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I got this error when trying to upgrade docker-ce on my debian machine.  Running `dockerd --debug` showed me that the issue was:

```
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: prior storage driver aufs is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; update the the daemon configuration and explicitly choose this storage drive
r to continue using it; visit https://docs.docker.com/go/storage-driver/ for more information
```

A bit of investigation at the supplied URL told me I needed to change my storage driver, so I edited `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to contain

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

and then was able to successfully finish the upgrade of docker-ce.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue, and the debugging command provided by @Zeitounator helped a lot but didn't resolve the issue outright.

The problem turned out to be I didn't have IPTables installed on Centos, which Docker needs. I used the following walkthrough to install, start and test them and docker started no problem afterwards.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-iptables-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating the kernel version and rebooting solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating the firewalld solved the problem (personal sandbox, so i just outright disabled the firewall entirely).

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the port in docker.service file works for me

file location */etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants*

port to change at this line **ExecStart**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Debian and I solved it by installing `docker.io` package - I previously saw in aptitude that it was recommended but not installed so I gave it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had invalid json objects in my etc/init.d/daemon.json file, in my case it was

```
}
  ...
  "features" : {
    ...
    "buildkit" : true
  }
}
```

which I changed to

```
}
   "features" : {
     "buildkit" : true
  }
}
```

and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Xero arc-based-linux distro.

1. restart my pc after docker installation
2. run the following command

```
    1. sudo systemctl status docker # inactive

    2. sudo systemctl start docker.service

    3. sudo systemctl status docker # active
```

hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to run `dockerd --debug` to see what the error was.

I found

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: list bridge addresses failed: PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks List: [192.168.99.0/24]: no available network
```

Then I had to follow steps from [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/123#issuecomment-346546953) to solve it

Basically running,

```
ip link add name docker0 type bridge
ip addr add dev docker0 172.17.0.1/16
```

in a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

For me when I type

```
sudo dockerd --debug
```

I got:

```
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: debug: (from flag: true, from file: true)
```

Solved it with following set of command:

```
sudo service firewalld stop
sudo service docker restart
sudo systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the command `sudo dockerd --debug` I saw this error in log

```
level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 9b0bc67bba1eda3158e363112e6a6efc0cfac1ac42ddc4c17c4
dockerd[20306]: panic: assertion failed: write: circular dependency occurred
```

Circular dependencies can happen when there are interdependent relationships between Docker components or configurations that create an infinite loop, causing Docker to encounter this error.
You can solve this by removing problematic container using

```
docker rm 9b0bc67bba1eda3158e363112e6a6efc0cfac1ac42ddc4c17c4
```

Or you can try removing all images and containers using this command. Use this with caution. As The command below will also remove volumes and networks.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
```

Another way is to simply `cd` into the mentioned directories above and only remove containers folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copy folder of docker into /user/bin and it not run. Just moving all docker/* into /user/bin