# How do i solve docker which can't running image?

Tags: docker

When i run `docker run hello-world` i got problem like this

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

what is the solution to solve this problem? I new with docker. thanks

Comment: *Is* the Docker daemon running? How have you installed and started Docker?

Comment: this simply tells you docker is not running. You must start the docker daemon first, then you can use docker commands in the terminal.

Comment: i have start. but still error with the message
```Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Could you provide more insights about your local machine? Windows? Linux? ... Also did you check the docker official forums for the usual errors that might cause this right after installation?

Comment: i use linux for run docker. the currently status when i see is ```docker.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE```

Comment: Could you post the output of `systemctl status docker.service`?

Comment: Also check status of `dockerd` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906503/how-to-fix-job-for-docker-service-failed-because-the-control-process-exited-wit)

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem with install docker as officially. In other word is Don't use snap!